# Titaniun Blur Event

Tags: modal-dialog, titanium, blur

I have a text field which I've assigned a blur event to check the input text when the user moves to another text field. If the text field for example is a numeric, the code will check for a numeric value and if it isn't, it then shows an alert box letting the user know.

The problem I have is that all of the text fields have a blur event, such when the user moves from text field A to text field B, the blur event fires and if it's empty, shows the dialogue box. The user clicking OK on the dialogue box then also fires the blur event on text field B which has yet to be completed. This causes a second dialogue box to be presented warning the user that text field B hasn't been populated. This is obvious since the user was moving from A to B.

My question after that rambling, is how do I stop any further blur events from firing whilst serving the original blur event?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you're exact problem... But you have options.

You can e.cancelBubble = true; or e.bubble = false; in the event handler function.

But it sounds also that this may work for you:

if (textField.value.length > 0 && isNaN(textField.value)) textField.blur(); // this way you blur it manually